Example using NASA GMAT to model a sounding rocket launch
I'm wondering if anyone has an example GMAT script that describes a sounding rocket launch and return. Not necessarily looking for high fidelity but just something that shows the parameters for a rocket sitting on a pad (zero velocity), to ignition, climbing to apogee, and returning through its ballistic trajectory.

GMAT is used for analysis of objects in orbits and/or moving on trajectories in space as influenced by propulsive forces and gravity and other space effects..  The problem you are looking at is highly influenced by atmospheric drag.  I don't believe GMAT even has any provisions for that.  I suggest looking at amateur rocket launch software (of which I am not familiar) or trying to work it out yourself from 1st principles..

In theory this could be accomplished using large mass spacecraft with huge burns but it would be very poorly modeled, as GMAT is focused on space rather than atmospheric components. All of the default atmospheric models crap out at or below around 90-100 km, so there would be little use in trying to model launches without any atmosphere.
